# How to create a custom framework package for WinJS (WinRT)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, expression-blend, winjs

The project templates for Visual Studio 2012 contain a reference package with javascript, localization files and styles.

[image: WinJS Framework Reference]

What I am wondering is how to build a custom reference package with my code, locales and styles. There is absolutely no information about this on the web, I tried referring to MSDN, but it did not give me any clue as to how I can do this. Please share any useful information that you may have about this.

It turns out Microsoft do have [documentation on Extension SDKs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh768146.aspx#ExtensionSDKs).

**Update:**

I actually managed to get the reference/framework package. It all works really well except when opening Expression Blend with my package referenced. Notice the reference is there and I can actually see all components and their description but I'm still getting an error in the design surface. Here is what the error looks like (I know, it's very descriptive):
[image: Expression blend with custom framework referenced]

**Update:**

When trying to deploy an app referencing the framework package I have created I being given an error saying that it cannot find my framework but instead finds some framework with trailing symbols that I did not put there while packaging it. It appends the processor architecture as well as the package family name trailing symbols. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item you are looking at is a "Framework Package". While it is possible for you to generate a package that looks like a framework package (look at the appxmanifest.xml for the WinJS package in `\Program Files\WindowsApps`), you cannot get that package ingested into the store.

This is something that is not supported in Win8 -- you'll need to include the files you need in each package you build.

Comment: I don't want to get the framework package itself on the Windows store. However if someone is building an app using my framework package, would they be able to successfully submit the app to the store?

Comment: They would need your package to be in the store. Without that, the silent magic downloading of dependencies would not happen.

this is ignoring the fact that the store won't ingest your app if it knows nothing about that framework package.

You would need to enable a "special" kind of build time MSBuild task or similar that would pull the files into the single package that would be submitted to the store.

Comment: I actually managed to get it working. However I have updated my question with issues I am having with expression blend